# AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, mysql, class, mysql-connector

I am using python to try and write/read with a mysql server that exists on same machine. I am in particular having troubles with defining read and write methods from some class, if I just use methods outside of classes I am having no issues.

To clarify:

```
# DATABASE STUFF
class DatabaseOperations:
    def __init__(self):
        self.local_ip = '192.168.105.181'  # LOCAL MACHINE SERVER RUNNING ON
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # SOCK_DGRAM refers to UDP
        self.s.connect((self.local_ip, 80))
        self.db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="myuser",
            password="12345",
            database="Testing"
        )

    def readFromDatabase(self):
        db_cursor = self.db_connection
        db_cursor.execute(
            f"select * from receiving;"
        )
        db_result = db_cursor.fetchall()
        print(db_result)

    def writeToDatabase(self):
        db_cursor = self.db_connection

        # Loop through ResultsLists and print value at given index position
        for i in range(len(globalResultsList)):
            print(f'RESULTS FROM LOOP: {globalResultsList[i]}')

            # If the next iterator is larger than the length of the list => break out of loop
            if i+1 >= len(globalResultsList):
                return

        db_cursor.execute(
            f"INSERT INTO receiving (client_ip, client_message) VALUES( '{globalClient}', '{globalResultsList[0]}');"
        )
        self.db_connection.commit()
        db_cursor.close()
```

If I copy the stuff from the **init** method directly into the read/write methods, so as I have two standalone methods, I can read and write no issues. I am struggling with making a class implementation work, does anyone know why given my pasted code I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'execute'
```